# Qualtric REST API

Tags: javascript, ajax, qualtrics

I am new to web development, currently building an html web app, where I need to get data from a Qualtric survey and use it to modify my web app.
I looked into Qualtric REST API here:https://survey.qualtrics.com/WRAPI/ControlPanel/docs.php#overview_2.4
and tried to follow it.
I added these lines to my javascript and it always gets me error 500.
Simply pasting the url to browser url bar gets me error 500, too.

Can anyone please help me on this? Thanks a lot!

```js
$(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://new.qualtrics.com/WRAPI/ControlPanel/api.php?Request=getUserInfo&User=xxxx&Token=xxxxxxxxx&Format=XML&Version=2.4',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('success', data);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me.  I think it is a problem with your user name.  When I use the wrong username, I get a 500 error.  When I use the wrong token I get a 401 error.

This url works for me (with the correct user and token):
https://new.qualtrics.com/WRAPI/ControlPanel/api.php?Version=2.4&Request=getUserInfo&User=username%40email.com&Token=XXXXX&Format=XML

Hint: If you login to Qualtrics, then go to Account/Qualtrics IDs, under API you can copy your token, then click the API Documentation link.  You can then click on the Try it! link under the command you want to execute, paste in your Token, and it will build the url for you with you user name included.

Comment: Thanks a lot! After several tries, I finally found the right use name I should be using. Now it opens in the browser. However, with AJAX, I says "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource". Is there a way to solve that? Do I eventually have to find some ways to put my web app in qualtrics.com? Thanks again!

Comment: That is a browser security issue. Since you have no control over the headers sent by the API, you probably need an intermediary server side script. Make your AJAX call to that script, then that script calls the api (e.g. php curl).  Your intermediary script can send the necessary headers to make the browser happy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have figured out that using pipe text and query string can do the thing I need. Still it's nice to know the solution to  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' though. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

HTTP status code 500 is a server error (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html). I don't have a username or token to test the API, but my guess is that you're not doing anything wrong - the API service could have a bug or something that is causing an unhandled exception.

Maybe you can contact Qualtrics support. Good luck :)

Comment: I know 500 is supposed to be a server error. I am just kinda skeptical of it being an API bug because I am not doing anything strange but just plainly following the API document. Thanks still!